# Docker volume with typescript

Tags: docker

I have a dockerfile for my TS app

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /usr
COPY package.json ./
COPY tsconfig.json ./
COPY src ./src
RUN ls -a
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 4005
CMD ["npm","run","dev"]
```

and I'm able to build it with this command

`docker build -t ts-prisma .`
and run it like this
`docker run -it -p 3000:4005  -v src-prisma:/usr/src ts-prisma`

What I want to achieve is to attach a volume to it and everytime I change something in my code change it in the docker.

I mean,
first time I build my app I have and endpoint like this

```
app.get(
    "/",
    async (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<Response> => {
        return res.status(200).send({
            message: "Hello world!!!",
        });
    }
);
```

and if I do a curl to ´http://localhost:3000´ it sends me the correct response of

```
{
   message: "Hello world!!!",
}
```

But if I change that for this

```
app.get(
    "/",
    async (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<Response> => {
        return res.status(200).send({
            message: "This is a new message",
        });
    }
);
```

I'm still getting the older message.

I access to the docker with
`docker exec -it <id> /bin/sh`
and do a cat of the index.ts file

and is still the first version of it, nothing changed.

What am I missing?

I know there is a way to do it with volumes but I couldn't figured out.

Comment: I think you can find the solution in [this video](https://youtu.be/5JQlFK6MdVQ).

Comment: If `npm run dev` runs the app using nodemon or if it's a CRA app you just need to bind-mount the `src` directory into the container instead of copying it.

Comment: When you run the container you have 3 copies of your source: 1 in the image, 1 on your host file system and 1 in the docker volume called `src-prisma`. Which one are you changing? I'm guessing the one on the host file system. The one you can see inside the container is the one in the `src-prisma` docker volume.

Comment: @HansKilian that's actually what I'm doing. Modifying the code in the source but it's not being modified in the container/volume and I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to run node in a container strictly for development, then you want to keep the source on your host drive and not have it in the container at all. So your COPY statements in the Dockerfile aren't necessary. You might actually be able to get away with running a completely standard node image.

Please note that I assume your host is a Linux or MacOS machine. If you're on Windows with WSL2, then doing this is hard(er) since file changes on the Windows file system aren't sent to Linux containers, so the container won't get notified when you make changes to your files.

To make sure that you have the necessary packages installed, we can run

```
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/src -w /src node:alpine npm install
```

That will install the packages you need on your host file system.

Now you can start your development environment with

```
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/src -p 3000:4005 -w /src node:alpine npm run dev
```

Now you should be able to change your files on your host file system and your container should pick up the changes.

When your app is done and you want to create a final image, you can do it with a Dockerfile like this

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /src
COPY . ./
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 4005
CMD ["npm", "run", "production"]
```

That image will have all your source code inside it, so once it's built, no changes to the code will have an effect on it unless you build it again.

To build it and run it, you'd do

```
docker build -t myimage .
docker run -p 3000:4005 myimage
```